# Slash in virtual directory name (IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have a website on IIS 6 running PHP. Let's say the address is:

```
http://mysite
```

I want to create a virtual directory to run an ASP.NET MVC 3 app under this address. I want the virtual directory to look like this:

```
http://mysite/api/v2
```

I cannot create a virtual directory called 'api/v2' because it contains slash. Is it possible to create virtual directory two levels down like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to create physical directory under the root called 'api' (this is possible in PHP), then create a virtual directory called 'v2' under that.

Answer (score 4):

It know it is stupid but for some weird reason you cannot type / in IIS7 under virtual directory but you can copy/paste value like app/v2 into that textbox. hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [following article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/11/22/virtual-application-vs-virtual-directory.aspx) for nesting virtual directories.